# What happens when AC voltage is supplied to DC equipment and vice versa?

Tags: voltage, ac, dc

I would like to know what would happen if a 240V AC supply is fed to a DC equipment panel or an electronic DC circuit and if a 250V DC supply was fed to an AC motor?

Comment: Most likely, it blows up.  In both cases.  The DC equipment probably can't handle that much variation, much less reverse polarity.  The AC motor (except for a universal one) depends on the AC's reversal to work at all, so it just sits there drawing tons of current without the fan running.

Answer (score 9):

> I would like to know what would happen if a 240V AC supply is fed to a DC equipment panel or an electronic DC circuit and if a 250V DC supply was fed to an AC motor?

Usually applying similar voltage DC to an AC rated device or AC voltage to a DC rated device leads to magic smoke, flames, bad smells and/or worse.
If Murphy cannot manage destruction then poor operation or no operation is common. Sometimes no bad effects occur and some equipment will operate on DC or AC -  sometimes within spec and sometimes not. eg a series would vacuum cleaner motor will operate on AC or DC. It MAY run faster on DC than AC at the same voltage. Or not.

**AC devices operated on DC:**

I'll comment on a range of AC based equipment even though you only asked about AC motors.

AC equipment often uses (usually inductive) components whose impedance depends on the frequency of the applied AC voltage. Their resistance to DC may be lower or much lower than their impedance ( = AC resistance) at operating frequency. A motor may have field coils and/or rotor coils both of which may be destroyed by excessive current when DC is applied.

In some cases the motor may survive but in almost all cases will not operate. An exception is the series-wound or universal motor where the relative polarity of the rotor and field coils determines motor direction - reverse polarity to both coils and motor direction remains unchanged. The most common example is the classic vacuum cleaner motor. Modern vacuum cleaners may use other types of motors.

Other AC rated equipment with inductive components (such as transformers) may also be destroyed by high currents from DC and will again usually not operate.

AC solenoids will usually operate on DC but will usually burn out rapidly or at some stage due to high currents.

Some AC rated devices immediately rectify the AC and use the DC - usually with filtering and may work acceptably well on DC. However, some devices may rely on the peak AC voltage being about 40% higher than the RMS value and may need a higher DC voltage. Some devices rectify the AC but use special circuits such as "hill and valley circuits" in some LED drivers and low voltage output power  supplies so may work badly or partially or not at all on DC.

**DC devices operated on AC:**

AC varies from DC of the same RMS voltage in having

- Higher peak voltages
- Reverse voltage for half of each cycle.
- Low voltage periods twice per cycle.
- Cyclical voltage variations across each half cycle.

The high voltages and reverse voltages may destroy some components (eg electrolytic capacitors, semi conductors, ...)

The cyclical variations and low voltages may appear in the system output - eg hum (possibly very bad) in audio equipment, chatter in relays etc.

Even if equipment survives the negative half cycles it may not operate or operate poorly on one half cycle and may not reset or restart properly in the brief time available.

Answer (score 1):

If AC is supplied to a circuit that has to run on DC then the DC equipment is likely to fail and burn.

If DC is supplied to an AC motor (not a rectified DC motor) then it's bad news again and, if the current that can be taken from the DC source is large enough, the motor will likely burn its windings and go open circuit.